# MS Access: Copy/Paste selected record programmatically?

Tags: ms-access, vba, copy, paste

Sorry for the lengthy introduction but I think it best to explain the context of my question. I have an Access 2003 database in which users need to create new records based upon pre-existing records already in the table. Some of the users of the database are more familiar with computers in general and create a new record by ...

```
1. Selecting a previous record in a datasheet and copying it (via right click -> Copy)
2. Selecting new row in the datasheet and "pasting" the previous record (via right click => Paste)
3. Edit the newly pasted row with the new data
```

This works fine as the table the datasheet is based on uses an "auto-number" field preventing duplicates. The problem I am having is that some of the users of this database are not so "computer-savy" and are having some difficulty with right-clicking etc ... I have been asked to create a button that ..

```
1. Copies the previous record
2. Inserts it into datasheet
```

The users can then edit the new record as needed. This leads me to my question. How do I go about copying a record and then inserting it into the datasheet programmatically in VBA? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Append query.

Some notes:

```
s = "Insert Into TableX (Field1, Field2, Field3) " _
  & "Select Field1, Field2, Field3 From TableX " _
  & "Where ID=" & Forms!TableXForm!ID

CurrentDb.Execute s

Forms!TableXForm.Requery
```